# Two libraries bring in different version of the same dependency. How to import them both?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have the following situation:

```
+ DentistApp
   L TreatsLibrary
     L IceCream 1.0
   L CavityCausesLib
     L IceCream 2.0
```

Now I get a `VerifyError` because `TreatsLibrary` is using `IceCream.giveToKidAfterDrill()` which was removed in version 2.0 because of legal reasons.

How do I import both versions and make sure that each uses its own?

Comment: This cannot be done by just using one ClassLoader as in one ClassLoader, only one version of the class can exist.

You may want to take a look at OSGi if you don't want to implement your own class loading mechanism.

Comment: Yes it can be done, I just don't remember how, it had to do with renaming libraries

Comment: You tagged this with sbt-assembly, which will only help you if you package your libraries using an uber JAR.

Comment: I am using a Uber jar

Comment: *"No they are not used in the project only in dependencies"* What does this have to do with what I've answered? Shading happens when you package your uber JAR, and at runtime these classes will have different package names

Comment: Alright. I now get it that `sbt-assembly` has the ability to shading the classes. https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer assumes you're talking about how to load these libraries from a packaged uber JAR at runtime.

You need to shade your dependencies using `sbt-assembly`.
This can be done as follows:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("IceCream.**" -> "my_icecream.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.library.treats" % "TreatsLibrary" % "1.0.0")
    .inProject
)
```

This will shade the `IceCream` dependency in your `com.library.treats` and change every package name to begin with `my_icecream`.

Comment: No they are not used in the project only in dependencies

Comment: @gurghet Not sure what that has to do with my answer. This will shade any dependency, regardless if it's written by you or packaged by a third party.

Comment: What does inproject do?

Comment: @gurghet Goes over all your library dependencies in your project. i.e. if it has a reference to `com.library.treats.TreatsLibrary` it now needs to change it to `my_icecream.TreatsLibrary`.

Comment: from the README:

`call .inProject to match your project source`

so no it would be useless

Comment: @gurghet If you change a librarys namespace, and your code references the old namespace, how will your code compile? Trust me, you need it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov but you still have the nonshaded IceCream 2.0 on your classpath, don't you? or else how does CavityCausesLib work?

Comment: @K.M I do, but now they have different artifact ids, so they no longer clash.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if the non-shaded one is still on the classpath, does that mean that the `.inProject` line is not necessary? if my code references the old namespace, the old namespace should still be there. however, i tried a setup similar to this, and it actually doesn't work without `.inProject` and I don't understand why. shouldn't my `IceCream.**` refs in my code still hit IceCream 2.0?